# Nested User Controls - where to start?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<uc:Tabs runat="server">
    <uc:ControlA runat="server" />
    <uc:ControlB runat="server" />
    <uc:ControlC runat="server" />
</uc:Tabs>
```

I'm trying to build a "Tabs" user control that will gather all of the controls nested within itself and wrap them in a specific set of html. Each nested user control should display normally. Any pointers to where I might begin?

Edit:

```
        <asp:Menu
            id="Menu1"
            StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="tab"
            StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="selectedTab"
            CssClass="tabs"
            OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick"
            Runat="server">
            <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Tab 1" Value="0" Selected="true" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Tab 2" Value="1" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Tab 3" Value="2" />
            </Items>    
        </asp:Menu>

        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" ActiveViewIndex="0" runat="server">
            <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                <hi5:GameInfo runat="server" />
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                <hi5:GamePlayerInfo runat="server" />
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
                <hi5:GuildInfo runat="server" />
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
```

I guess I could use `asp:Menu` and `asp:MultiView` and wrap each with the appropriate classes.

Wish I could remove the auto generated css that asp:Menu puts into the `<head>` though. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an MSDN VB solution which could be easily translated to C#.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319100

However depending on what you are trying to accomplish, this sounds like it may be an overcomplicated or overkill solution for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you're right about this being a bit of overkill. just running that code above, I get: Type 'ASP.usercontrols_tabs_ascx' does not have a public property named 'ControlA'.

Comment: sounds like the user control is not registered at the top of the page.  have ControlA, B, C is somewhat counter intuitive to the use of a user control.  User controls are there for the re-use of code.  Here it seems like you wouldn't be reusing anything therefore you need to programatically add the controls to your page so you can use the same control over and over again.

Comment: so say I'm on Page.aspx, on Page.aspx, I @Register Tabs, ControlA, ControlB, ControlC. When I nest them like so, I get an error that ControlA/B/C aren't registered on Tabs.ascx, not on Page.aspx. I'm trying to avoid having to @Register things in Tabs.ascx in order to use them.

Comment: I found another mechanism (asp:Menu and asp:MultiView) that would allow me to achieve some sort of tab effect. I have edited the question showing this.